# LED case connectors on a motherboard

Tags: motherboard, wiring, led

I have the following configuration on the F_PANEL LED connectors on my motherboard:

[image]

However, I have just three two-pin wires in my case (called POWER_SW, H.D.D_LED and POWER_LED).

Do you have any ideas how to fit those into the pins on the motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 and 8, 2 and 4, 3 and 5. Note that the latter two are polarized, and will need to be reversed if they don't light up, or light up incorrectly (reversing them accidentally will *not* cause any damage though).